# Insert text below hyperlinked image?

Tags: html, image

I am working within a CMS that was made specifically for our company. I'm trying to figure out how to insert text below this image. If i could get the text to be centered within the pictures boarder, that would be great. I am only to edit in HTML and cannot access or make style sheets...I think...Below is the code.

```
<a href="/products/details/for-the-hair/shampoo-bars/extra-honey-beer-shampoo">
    <img alt="Extra Honey Shampoo" src="/_CE/pagecontent/Images/idascorner/extrahoneypoo.jpg" class="pull-image-right" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin-top: 20px;" />
</a>
```

Comment: you did not add any code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want it, you could go with:

```
<a href="/products/details/for-the-hair/shampoo-bars/extra-honey-beer-shampoo">
 <img alt="Extra Honey Shampoo" src="/_CE/pagecontent/Images/idascorner/extrahoneypoo.jpg" class="pull-image-right" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin-top: 20px;"><br>
 YOUR TEXT HERE
</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="/products/details/for-the-hair/shampoo-bars/extra-honey-beer-shampoo">
 <img alt="Extra Honey Shampoo" src="/_CE/pagecontent/Images/idascorner/extrahoneypoo.jpg" class="pull-image-right" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin-top: 20px;">
</a><br>
YOUR TEXT HERE
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried your suggestion as listed above but the text doesn't display under the image. The text Displays at the very top of the page... Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: You might need to check your CSS. My guess is that there is something attached to either `img {}` or `.pull-image-right {}` that's misplacing the text, like `position: absolute`.